# How to clear screen without ```screen.fill((0, 0, 0)```?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, window

I am making a game where when you touch the wall, you have to click a rectangle to move on.

However, the rectangle is displayed, but so is the previous screen.

I can't use `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))` because in the loop, it will just keep going. 
I want to delete the screen(or withdraw it temporarily. This is preferred).

Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False
x = 100

y = 100
#button1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 30, 30))

    #if check <= pos - (w/2) and check >= 
pygame.display.set_caption("Auto Maze!")
donk = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse = event.pos
            try:
                assert button1.collidepoint(mouse)
            except AssertionError:
                pass
            except NameError:
                pass
            else:
                donk = True
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= 5
    elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
        y += 5
    elif pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= 5
    elif pressed[pygame.K_d]:
        x += 5
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    try:
        assert player.colliderect(wall1)
    except AssertionError:
        pass
    except NameError:
        pass
    else:
        death_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
        button1 = pygame.draw.rect(death_screen, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 30, 30))
        if donk:
            break


    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 60, 60))
    wall1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (400, 300, -100, -300))

    clock.tick(60)  
    pygame.display.flip()

quit()
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: FYI, if it is impossible to close or withdraw the screen, please tell me how to stop in the loop without the program crashing and going into an infinite loop. Thanks!

Comment: `continue` will return to the top of the loop. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This helped me with another aspect of the game. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the try and except and i think it does what you want

```
player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 60, 60))
wall1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (300, 0, 100, 300))    


if player.colliderect(wall1):
    death_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
    button1 = pygame.draw.rect(death_screen, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 30, 30))
    if donk:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! This really cleaned my code, and I also learnt a little about control flow.